# Programatically finding out when a google account is last accessed

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-account

Is there a way to pull the last accessed date of a google/gmail account assuming you have all the right permissions and your app is authorized?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with Gmail API alone but I think you can use the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-gmail), using `last_access_time`, `last_interaction_time` or `last_webmail_time` you can get the last access of the user's account, the last active interaction by the user's account and time of last user access of the web Gmail account. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Hey, thanks for your reply but I think the admin SDK is only specific to custom accounts on google mail, not generic gmail accounts.